# Azure Service Bus: Firewalls and virtual networks

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Let me clarify one details regarding Service Bus Premium feature: "Firewalls and virtual networks"

I have configured internal virtual network and filled other network which I'am using for service bus integration.

Unfortunately, I faced the issue with huge impact for me: it is not possible to use Function App(ASE) together with Service bus in case of Service Bus firewall is enabled.

So, the main point here: How to determine which IP address should be whitelisted in Service Bus firewall to allow traffic from Function Apps? Or maybe another possible working solution for this.

As a good example, it would be great if button "Allow access to Azure services"( like in PostgreSQL) will be implemented in Service Bus for such cases.

Comment: Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses. HTH.

Comment: Gaurav, thank you for your response. It seems that such information is very helpful for me. I will test it and return back to you with result.

Comment: Awesome! If you find a solution to your problem, please post it here as an answer. That will be super helpful to others IMHO.